# Store a collection of Ruby objects

Tags: ruby, oop

I am trying to store a collection of objects within another object. I completed a coding challenge that looks like the following.

First the singular object:

```
class Account
  attr_reader :user_name, :credit, :debit

  def initialize(user_name)
    @user_name = user_name
    @credit = 0
    @debit = 0
  end
end
```

Next the collection:

```
class AccountsCollection
  attr_reader :accounts

  def initialize
    @accounts = []
  end

  def add_new_account(user)
    accounts << Account.new(user)
  end

  ...
end
```

This is how I use it:

```
accounts = AccountsCollection.new
# => #<AccountsCollection:0x00007fc76ba70b18 @accounts=[]>
accounts.add_new_account('A')
accounts.add_new_account('B')
accounts.add_new_account('C')
accounts.accounts
# =>[
#     #<Account:0x00007fc76b933890 @user_name="A">,
#     #<Account:0x00007fc76bc76d68 @user_name="B">,
#     #<Account:0x00007fc76c88c2d8 @user_name="C">
#   ]
```

I wanted to use it like this:

```
class Display
  attr_reader :accounts

  def initialize(accounts)
    @accounts = accounts
  end

  def display_inline
    accounts.each do |account|
      #do something
  end
  ...
end

Display.new(accounts.accounts).display_inline
```

But I have to call `accounts.accounts` to obtain the list of account objects. Is this weird? Can anyone show me how I can do this better?

Comment: _"had to call accounts.accounts to obtain the list"_ – well, the list should be encapsulated within `AccountsCollection`. Why do you need / want to have direct access to it?

Comment: The question here is why you needed a new class in the first place? With the current implementation I would just use a plain array. If there is some more significant functionality there, it will guide you to a better name. Anyway, if for whatever reason you stick with `AccountsCollection`, just rename the `accounts` method to `to_a`.

Comment: @ndn owh that's because i left out a few attributes.there are other attrs such as credit, debit and balance. Sorry I should have included it in there.

I left out another method for accountscollection, which is create or initialize
get_user(name) || add_new_account(name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code smell, IMO, with your code is simply that it's a collection, but I can't treat it like a collection. For instance, if I wanted all the accounts that had more than 10 credits, I would have to pull the array of accounts out of the collection to do it:

```
accounts.accounts.select { |account| account.credit > 10 }
```

whereas what you'd really want is to be able to just query the collection for it:

```
accounts.select { |account| account.credit > 10 }
```

To make your collection feel more like a collection, you need to include [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) which requires that you implement the `each` method:

```
class AccountsCollection
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    @accounts = []
  end

  def add(user_name)
    @accounts << Account.new(user_name)

    self # return self because that's more in-line with other collections
  end

  def each
    return to_enum(__method__) { @accounts.size } unless block_given?

    @accounts.each { |account| yield account }
  end
end
```

and with just that you can now treat your collection like the other collections in ruby:

```
accounts = AccountsCollection.new
accounts.add('A').add('B').add('C')

accounts.each.with_index do |account, index|
  # I changed the attr_reader in Account to attr_accessor just to illustrate
  account.credit = index * 10
end

accounts.select { |account| account.credit > 10 }
# => [#<Account:0x00007fe50d894208 @user_name="C", @credit=20, @debit=0>]
```

and if you want it as an array, you automatically got a `to_a` method as well:

```
accounts.to_a
# => [#<Account:0x00007f879a094538 @user_name="A", @credit=0, @debit=0>,
#     #<Account:0x00007f879a094308 @user_name="B", @credit=10, @debit=0>,
#     #<Account:0x00007f879a0968b0 @user_name="C", @credit=20, @debit=0>]
```

this (by default) will create a new array by going through the `each` method so the array won't be directly modified (though the contents still can be)

```
accounts.to_a[1].debit = 15
accounts.to_a << 'not an account'

accounts.to_a
# => [#<Account:0x00007fb51c08a9c0 @user_name="A", @credit=0, @debit=0>,
#     #<Account:0x00007fb51c08a6a0 @user_name="B", @credit=10, @debit=15>,
#     #<Account:0x00007fb51c08a588 @user_name="C", @credit=20, @debit=0>]
```

You can always replace any method of `Enumerable` with a better, custom implementation if you want:

```
def to_a
  @accounts.dup
end
```

Now things are starting to feel and smell a whole lot better, with minimal work, and others trying to use your `AccountsCollection` will be thoroughly pleased that they have access to all the search and traversal methods they're used to.

Comment: Thank you Simple Line! This is very helpful. =)

Answer (score 2):

Really it looks good to me other than the naming looking awkward. If it was me, I'd have the names like this so it looks good using it.

```
class AccountsCollection
  def initialize
    @accounts = []
  end

  def add(user)
    accounts << Account.new(user)
  end

  def to_a
    @accounts
  end
end
```

Then your code would look like

```
accounts = AccountsCollection.new
 => #<AccountsCollection:0x00007fc76ba70b18 @accounts=[]>

accounts.add('A')
accounts.add('B')
accounts.add('C')

accounts.to_a
 =>[
   #<Account:0x00007fc76b933890 @user_name="A">,
   #<Account:0x00007fc76bc76d68 @user_name="B">,
   #<Account:0x00007fc76c88c2d8 @user_name="C">
 ]
```

Comment: It can be argued that `show` might not be the best name here. Assuming that you want to extract an array from this collection, the idiomatic ruby way would be to use the `to_a` method.

Comment: Right, I agree `to_a` would be better. Updated, thanks

Comment: You might want to `dup` the array to prevent direct modification.